# Inconsistent border widths on pseudo-elements because of translate3d -- but why?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, translate3d

*(I've tried searching for this but can't seem to describe it correctly--if this answer exits, please point me in the right direction!)*

I'm playing around with some css rules. I wanted to make a specific, secondary 2px-wide border on a pseudo-element appear around nav anchors in the header, which open a modal and blur an absolutely-positioned background image div #bg, which sits as such:

```
<body>
  <div id="#bg"></div>
  <header id="global-header">
    <nav>...</nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Since I wanted to transition the blur effect, I added translate3d(0,0,0) to #bg, which smoothed the fps by galvanizing the GPU for hardware accelerated processing of CSS. It worked! ...Until I noticed that the vertical (left & right) borders for the links had inconsistent widths across the nav. They were each set at 2px, but every other one looked 1.5(??)px wide. It took me a minute to narrow down why, which ultimately was because of the translate3d transformation. I took screenshots, but I centered and  moved the pseudo-elements with **border-left: 2px** below the header (the effect persisted), and I removed the background image itself so the effect would be easier to see. Here they are:

- [Inconsistent 2px calculation (with translate3d(0,0,0) on #bg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxK3u.png)
- [Consistent widths (without translate3d transform on #bg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjecm.png)

And for reference, here's the code for the left-bordered pseudo-elements:

```
#global-header nav ul li a:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 0; 
 border-left: 2px solid gray;
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

I know that translate3d creates as well as solves a possible host of issues from my searches--but why is *this* happening? Does it have anything to do with "subpixel calculations"? And why would these calculations render inconsistently throughout the page with hardware acceleration, on something I would assume is hard to mess up?

Edit: So, even without translate3d, the problem-lines flicker to a smaller width when the blur transitions (seen in the code from screenshots) are triggered, and I can reproduce the original issue without translate3d if I add **backface-visibility: hidden** to the pseudo-element itself. This could hint at general pixel rounding issues, with specific properties as triggers only being a symptom.

Comment: I recently had an issue with pixel rounding. If the amount of pixels available do not allow your elements to divide equally among the space, some will experience weird rounding, especially if you play with transforms.

Comment: @damanptyltd per your comment, I did a little more fiddling and edited my post.

Comment: I am glad to be of some help, but its unfortunate it hasn't fostered a solution for you. Sadly I do not have the time to demo and solve this, but for my project I solved it by padding the outer element with enough pixels that the number of elements divided exactly by the number of pixels available. I had this inside an on resize event so it was always correct at any browser size.

Answer (score 0):

After further fiddling, answering my own question: This *is not* caused caused by hardware acceleration, which was my revised suspicion. Though the use of these effects showcased the problem in my particular case, I was able to recreate a version of my issue without them.

By removing transform3d from the #bg element:

```
 #bg {
  .
  .
  .
   /* transform: translate3d(0,0,0); */
 }
```

And, without the backface-visibility property as well, I added some width to the pseudo-element in order to see what these borders would normally look like:

```
#global-header nav ul li a:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 /* top: 100%; */
 /* left: 50%; */
 height: 72px;
 width: 1px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 /* backface-visibility: hidden; */
 /* border-left: 2px solid black; */
 background-color: transparent;
 /* transition: height .2s ease; */
}
```

**Duh:** I should have expected the result, since earlier I had tried to use the element itself (by making it 1-2px wide and coloring it) instead of border-left, which at the time seemed to fix the issue. *Of course,* when I did it this time using the above css, [the base problem reappeared.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp1PK.png)

Though I still don't know why the aforementioned properties showcased the problem with **border-left** as well, addressing this might be too sporadic/situation-dependent to field here, and likely still has more to do with browser rendering than anything else.

Anyway, my question was why transform3d **caused** this effect, and the answer is, at least in this case, it didn't--it just made it more obvious.